# Como adicionar o teste da pluralsight no meu perfil?

Tags: suporte

Eu recebi hoje um e-mail da stack me apontando esse link [site para medir habilidade em código](https://www.pluralsight.com/) realizei alguns testes e clickei no botão que publicava o meu resultado no meta, o problema é que ele manda isso para um perfil meu no stack em inglês e eu não sei como faço para adicionar isso no perfil que eu realmente uso (stack em português), já que não encontrei opção para isso lá no site.

Comment: Ele altera o texto do perfil? Foi isso que eu entendi

Comment: Isso aí vai no DS que está vinculado ao SOen.

Comment: não @JeffersonQuesado, ele adiciona isso como uma conquista numa tal de "linha do tempo do programador" e fica como uma referência do que você sabe, mas infelizmente não está disponível no SO de português. Me pergunto se eles pretendem adicionar isso aqui também...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse indicador (IQ Pluralsight) é um recurso do developer story que está apenas disponível/vinculado ao SOen.

**Relaciondas:**

[Add an assessment to your Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362730/1342547)

[Pluralsight & Stack Overflow: Helping the World’s Developers Learn New Skills](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/02/06/pluralsight-stack-overflow-helping-worlds-developers-learn-new-skills/)